# Is there a difference in performance when swapping if/else condition?

Tags: c, performance, if-statement

Is there a difference in performance between

```
if(array[i] == -1){
    doThis();
}
else {
    doThat();
}
```

and

```
if(array[i] != -1){
    doThat();
}
else {
    doThis();
}
```

when I already now that there is only one element (or in general few elements) with the value -1 ?

Comment: No. This is useful only when cheating in homeworks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Comment: second doesn't compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance is always implementation dependent. If it is sufficiently important to you, then you need to benchmark it in your environment.

Having said that: there is *probably* no difference, because modern compilers are likely to turn both versions into equally efficient machine code.

One thing that might cause a difference is if the different code order changes the compiler's branch prediction heuristics. This can occasionally make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 7):

That will depend entirely on how your compiler chooses to optimise it. You have no guarantee as to which is faster. If you really need to give hints to the compiler, look at the `unlikely` macro in the Linux kernel which are defined thus:

```
#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
```

Which means you can use

```
if (likely(something)) { ... }
```

or

```
if (unlikely(something)) { ... }
```

Details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Moral: write your code for readability, and not how you think the compiler will optimise it, as you are likely to be wrong.

Comment: Wow, `__builtin_expect` is very neat! Using GCC's `-S` option to output assembly code for an if..then statement, using `likely` vs. `unlikely` actually inverts the order of the if..then (when using GCC optimization, `-O2` or `-O3` flag). E.g., `if (unlikely(something)) a(); else b();` produces the same assembly code as `if (!something) b(); else a();`. Thus, the moral of the story: Don't put more-likely-to-be-executed statements in an else; there are a few more calls in the assembly to process an else.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler wouldn't know about your actual data, so it will produce roughly the same low-level code.

However, given that if-statements generate assembly branches and jumps, your code may run *a little* faster in your second version because if your value is not -1 then your code will run the very next instruction. Whereas in your first version the code would need to *jump* to a new instruction address, which may be costly, especially when you deal with a large number of values (say millions).

Comment: +1, but it is not only about the jump into the condition but also from the condition to the continuation. If both codes would be placed on after another, there would be no difference: one would have a jump on entering and the other one on leaving.

Comment: Assuming it's more likely `array[i] != -1` is true (which is probably good assumption)

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on which condition is encountered first. As such there is not such a big diffrence.

`----->` If You have to test a lot of statements, rather than using nested `if-else` a `switch` statement would be faster.